# JVM options on Sbt Native Packager

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

I can't find a way to specify the -X options (-Xmx / Xms) when using SBT Native Packager when using a Java Archetype.

I tried to use a jvmopts file that contains those properties within src/universal folder. Adding to build.sbt

bashScriptConfigLocation := Some("${app_home}/../conf/jvmopts")

All these according to the following link: http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/archetypes/java_app/customize.html

I can't get it to modify the default 1024m values.

Comment: Could you show your jvmopts? What version do you use?

Comment: Or provide a small build example for demonstrate this case :)

Comment: I'm using 1.0.0-M4 and my jvmopts file is very simple,  contains 2 lines.
-Xms2048m
-Xmx2048m

But I think I found the problem after debugging the script file. 

It seems that you can't specify the jvm memory options directly on the jvmopts file as I'm doing currently.

The script has a "mem" argument that I could use as: -mem 2048.

Another way would be to set up JVM_OPTS environment variable, the script looks there too. 

And the other option is to add to AddJava in the build.sbt file.

bashScriptExtraDefines += """addJava "-Xms2048m""""
bashScriptExtraDefines += """addJava "-Xmx2048m""""

Comment: @leonfs, your second solution worked well for me. Consider adding it as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to prefix the -X options. Take a look at the example [etc-default](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/blob/master/src/main/resources/com/typesafe/sbt/packager/archetypes/etc-default-template) file.

So you would need to write in your `jvmopts`

```
-J-Xms1024m
-J-Xmx2048m
```

**UPDATE**

The `etc-default` behaviour has been corrected with version `1.0.0-RC2`. Take a look at the [server configuration page.](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/archetypes/java_server/customize.html#application-configuration)

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that `${app_home}` can only be used in `bashScriptExtraDefines`, not in `javaOptions`?

Comment: Yes. The ${app_home} is a value calculated at runtime.